# How to make filenames in German display properly after executing from a bat file?

Tags: character-encoding, rename, special-characters, batch-rename

I have a bat file that renames odd English filenames to German ones.
Characters are displayed correctly when composing the command in Notepad++. When I save it to the target folder and double click to execute it, the files were renamed, but some umlauts were displayed incorrectly. Can you tell me how to solve this? Please answer in a very simple manner as I'm not a developer, only a regular guy.

I tried different character encodings especially UTF-8 since it worked well on other languages I batch-renamed before but still no luck.

UPDATE: A great colleague helped me resolve this by suggesting the following codes:

```
chcp 65001 > nul
*rename lines*
chcp 1252 > nul
```

And these codes did the job for me :) Thank you all!

Comment: You need to post a minimum reproductible example along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct character encoding when you save your file. The first step is to find out which code page your command prompt uses. So open your command prompt and execute `chcp`.

Then save your batch file with this encoding.